# NullPointerException When Creating New Intent From Inner Class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I am having a bit of a problem. I have an activity class that has an inner class that extends AsyncTask. In the `onProgressUpdate()` I am trying to create a new Intent. When I try to crate the Intent object I get a NullPointerException. This is the line that is causing the exception:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OuterClassActivity.this, OuterClassActivity.class);.
```

The inner class searches a database. When the search is done I call `publishProgress()` and in `onProgressUpdate()` is where I am trying to create this intent to start the OuterClassActivity so it can display the results.

I have been searching around for a few hours now and cant find anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about why you need to create a new Activity each time publishProgress is called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use Intent for calling the outerclass? To my understanding, Intent is used to call a different view. Instead call a method that's defined in the outerclass to display the results.

Comment: I placed this method in a separate activity in the same package 

protected void startOtherActivity() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipeSearchActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

I create an instance of the other activity and call this startOtherActivity() and I still get a NullPointerException at this line Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipeSearchActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just update the current view instead of creating a new Activity ?
Could you be more specific about why you need to create a new Activity ?